# How to check if a Tuple of Points is connected with another Tuple?

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I have a list of tuples of points

```
[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]

[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]

[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]

[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]
```

Is there a way to check if two tuples are connected, where two tuples are connected when one coordinate is equal. You can also think of it as a graph. For example:

```
[(1,1),(2,2)]

[(1,1),(4,5)]

[(4,5),(2,3)]

[(5,6),(7,8)]
```

This is the list. Tuple 1 is connected to tuple 3, because you have first the connection point 1,1 and then the connection point 4,5.
However, tuple 1 is not connected to tuple 4 because there is no way there.

Comment: Well, have you tried something on your own?

Comment: This is an example of union find in graph theory as MBo pointed out in his answer. Check out [union find by path compression](https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/disjoint-set-union-find-algorithm-union-by-rank-and-path-compression/) if the list size is very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just do a recursive search of ways from one tuple to the other.

So in short: You create a stack of tuples. At first it will contain only your starting tuple. Then you look, which tuples you can reach directly from the starting tuple. For each of them you do the following:
Add it to the stack, test, if it is the target tuple (return true in this case -> a way is found!), rerun the search with the enlarged stack and finally remove the tuple from the stack.

Here is the way I would do it:

```
class Tuple {

  int x1, x2, y1, y2;

  public Tuple(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
  }

  boolean isDirectlyConnectedWith(Tuple tuple) {
    return (this.x1 == tuple.x1 && this.y1 == tuple.y1)
        || (this.x2 == tuple.x2 && this.y2 == tuple.y2)
        || (this.x1 == tuple.x2 && this.y1 == tuple.y2)
        || (this.x2 == tuple.x1 && this.y2 == tuple.y1);
  }
}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String args[]){

    Set<Tuple> tuples = new HashSet<>();
    Tuple tuple1 = new Tuple(1,1,2,2);
    Tuple tuple2 = new Tuple(1,1,4,5);
    Tuple tuple3 = new Tuple(4,5,2,3);
    Tuple tuple4 = new Tuple(5,6,7,8);
    tuples.addAll(Arrays.asList(tuple1, tuple2, tuple3, tuple4));

    System.out.println("Tuples 1 and 3 are connected: " + areTuplesConnected(tuples, tuple1, tuple3));
    System.out.println("Tuples 1 and 4 are connected: " + areTuplesConnected(tuples, tuple1, tuple4));
  }

  static boolean areTuplesConnected(Set<Tuple> tuples, Tuple t1, Tuple t2) {
    LinkedList<Tuple> stack = new LinkedList<>();
    stack.addLast(t1);
    return processSearchStep(tuples, stack, t2);
  }

  static boolean processSearchStep(Collection<Tuple> allTuples, LinkedList<Tuple> currentStack, Tuple targetTuple) {
    Set<Tuple> possibleNextTuples = allTuples.stream()
        .filter(t -> !currentStack.contains(t) && t.isDirectlyConnectedWith(currentStack.getLast()))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    for (Tuple nextTuple : possibleNextTuples) {
      currentStack.addLast(nextTuple);
      if (nextTuple.equals(targetTuple)) {
        return true;
      }
      if (processSearchStep(allTuples, currentStack, targetTuple)) {
        return true;
      }
      currentStack.removeLast();
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using equal coordinates as links, build [disjoint-set_data_structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), then you can check whether two tuples belong to the same component or not.